# Replace values conditionally over multiple columns with mutate in R

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have a data frame with 56 columns. I need to replace values with NA in 50 columns conditional on the value of the column "positive == 0".

I have figured out how to replace values in a single column conditionally with mutate. I have spent quite some time now to figure out how to apply this mutate function to other columns without having to reproduce the command 50 times - to no avail.

There has to be a simple solution. ;) Can somebody help?

This is the structure of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(positive = c(1,1,0,0,1),
                 a = c("x","x","x","y","y"),
                 b = c("z","z","z","y","z"),
                 d = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

This is my solution to replace values in one column.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(a = replace(a, positive == 0, NA))
```

Comment: Have you tried mutate(across())?

Comment: I have come across across on my search for solutions. :) But my coding skills are too poor to apply it to this problem. 

Also, I do not need to recode all my 56 columns. Just ~ 50 need to be recoded on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(-positive,-d), ~replace(.,positive == 0, NA)))
```

---

[Previous incorrect solution—does replace values with NA, but converts other values to 1. May still be useful to show different ways of selecting columns in the `across()` call.]

This seems to work:

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(-positive,-d), ~na_if(positive, 0)))
```

Here I've assumed you want to mutate all columns except 'positive' and 'd', but if you'd rather specify the columns you could say:

```
df %>% mutate(across(c('a', 'b'), ~na_if(positive, 0)))
```

Or, as in the dplyr [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/na_if.html) for the `na_if` function, you could use a characteristic of the columns you want to specify them:

```
df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(positive, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works to replace with NAs as I need it.

However, for some reason the other values in the recoded columns are replace with 1s. I can't figure out how comes.

Comment: This happens after I apply `df %>% mutate(across(c(-positive,-d), ~na_if(positive, 0))) ` or `df %>% mutate(across(c('a', 'b'), ~na_if(positive, 0)))`

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure why that's happening but this should work: `df %>% mutate(across(c(-positive,-d), ~replace(.,positive == 0, NA)))`

Comment: Let me know if it does and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hi Elle, 

Yes, this does indeed solve this issue!